# Installing Linux and then Window

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows

I have windows 8 installed. I want to remove it completely and install Linux first. Then later I **might** need to install Windows 7 as well.

I'm installing Linux from a bootable USB right now. If I choose "Remove Windows 8 completely and install Linux instead of it" in a dialog and take all the space of my disk for Linux (ext4), will I be able to "take a part of it back" later (when I **want** to install Windows), format it into ntfs and install Windows 7 there along with Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you may take it back, you may resize/shrink/move the ext4 partition using Gparted. You need to update-grub when you wanna do this.

But when you decided to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu has been installed, you will have to leave an unallocated partition before the partition where Ubuntu was installed. So using Gparted, you will provide a space for Windows 7, leave an un-allocated space on the left side.

When you install Windows after Ubuntu, windows 7 bootloader will take over and you will not be able to boot Ubuntu. so you need to fix your Grub Boot Loader, and let it handle your dual-boot mode.

So you might wanna read some more info about it, below are some helpful links:

- [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
- [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)
- [Google Search](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?gws_rd=cr#fp=6ebd6fd2b7587961&q=dual%20boot%20windows%207%20and%20ubuntu%20ubuntu%20installed%20first)

Goodluck